# sendmail not sending [stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with ...]

Tags: debian, sendmail, debian-stretch

novice trying to use sendmail for the first time. only issue mails never arrive (not even in spam) I have the following logs:

**mail.err** is empty

**mail.log** shows `accepted for delivery` but I also get `stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` sometime but not always so not sure if this could this be the issue ?

I already checked that port 25 is open with `netstat -tuplen | grep 25`

**Mail.log:**

```
Feb 17 16:57:16 mysite sendmail[1457]: w1HGvG6p001457:     to=myemail@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30423, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w1HGvG8t001458 Message accepted for delivery)

Feb 17 17:00:09 mysite sm-mta[689]: w1HGiDDr003604: to=.   <myemail@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mysite.com> (33/33), delay=00:15:56, xdelay=00:10:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120652, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.28.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

**mqueue** file is like this:

```
V8
T1518886636
K0
N0
P30652
Fbs
$_localhost [127.0.0.1]
$rESMTP
$smysite.com
${daemon_flags}
${if_addr}127.0.0.1
S<www-data@mysite.com>
A<>
rRFC822; myemail@gmail.com
RPFD:<mysite@gmail.com>
H?P?Return-Path: <�g>
H??Received: from mysite.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mysite.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-8) with ESMTP id w1HGvG8t001458
    for <mysite@gmail.com>; Sat, 17 Feb 2018 16:57:16 GMT
H?x?Full-Name: www-data
H??Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by bikecomparator.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id w1HGvG6p001457;
    Sat, 17 Feb 2018 16:57:16 GMT
H??Date: Sat, 17 Feb 2018 16:57:16 GMT
H??Message-Id: <201802171657.w1HGvG6p001457@mysite.com>
H??To: myemail@gmail.com
H??Subject: Signup | Verification
H??X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:userMgmt.php
H??From:noreply@mysite.com.com
```

**netstat -ntlp | grep sendmail**

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      687/sendmail: MTA:  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      687/sendmail: MTA:
```

**hosts**
`127.0.0.1 localhost mysite.com`

**hotname**
`mysite.com`

**/etc/mail/sendmail.mc**

```
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`$Id: sendmail.mc, v 8.15.2-8 2016-12-08 18:43:49 cowboy Exp $')
OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        #DAEMON_HOSTSTATS=
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
dnl #
dnl # General defines
dnl #
dnl # SAFE_FILE_ENV: [undefined] If set, sendmail will do a chroot()
dnl #   into this directory before writing files.
dnl #   If *all* your user accounts are under /home then use that
dnl #   instead - it will prevent any writes outside of /home !
dnl #   define(`confSAFE_FILE_ENV',             `')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
dnl # If you want to support IPv6, switch the commented/uncommentd  lines
dnl #
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp,     Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp,      Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea,  Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Be somewhat anal in what we allow
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',dnl`needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Define connection throttling and window length
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `15')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`10m')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Features
dnl #
dnl # use /etc/mail/local-host-names
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The access db is the basis for most of sendmail's checking
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The greet_pause feature stops some automail bots - but check  the
dnl # provided access db for details on excluding localhosts...
FEATURE(`greet_pause', `1000')dnl 1 seconds
dnl #
dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking
FEATURE(`delay_checks', `friend', `n')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If we get too many bad recipients, slow things down...
define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE',`3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Stop connections that overflow our concurrent and time connection rates
FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If you're on a dialup link, you should enable this - so    sendmail
dnl # will not bring up the link (it will queue mail for later)
dnl define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE',`True')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Dialup/LAN connection overrides
dnl #
include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Default Mailer setup
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You outgoing smtp connection may be blocked by your ISP (as outgoing spamprevention).

Do you get SMTP greeting message when you telnet SMTP port of any gmail.com MXes **from the host**? [Is it sendmail's fault?]

To get list of gmail MXes use: `dig MX gmail.com`

To get/check SMTP greeting use: `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`

Comment: telnet is stuck at `Trying 64.233.167.27...` I need to change port ?

Comment: You may use `tcptraceroute` (not simple `traceroute`) to detect firewall location.

Comment: ok I didt it and Im only getting `traceroute to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (64.233.167.27), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *` Does that mean my host is blocking it ? Im using vultr

Comment: actually a quick google shows that vultr blocks port 25 :( not sure how to get around it; I opened a ticket

Comment: In [vultr](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-exim-to-send-email-using-gmail-in-debian) they provide this solution using exim.

Comment: support say they will unblock the port for me apparently

Comment: all working now :)

Answer (score 1):

## Receiving emails:

Based on your `netstat -ntlp | grep sendmail` output, your server is just listening in localhost (127.0.0.1), not in your IP address.
If you want to receive emails, check [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-is-only-accepting-connections-from.html).

## Sending emails:

### Verify:

- DNS: `host -t mx gmail.com`. The answer looks like this:

  ```
  gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
  gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
  gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
  gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
  gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
  ```
- More DNS: `host alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` (or another gmail SMTP server). The answer looks like this:

  ```
  alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 209.85.202.27
  alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400b:c00::1a
  ```
- SMTP port access: `nc -vv alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` You should receive a 220 code:

  ```
  220 mx.google.com ESMTP 7si2060923qty.86 - gsmtp [831 ms]
  ```

If not, maybe your ISP is blocking port 25 and you could try use SMTP over SSL (port 465) or SMTP Submission (port 587).

Comment: the first two are ok but the last returns `DNS fwd/rev mismatch: alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com != pc-in-f26.1e100.net` I need to change port ?

Comment: Do you get a 220 code? Or something like "Ncat: Network is unreachable."

Comment: And try this:  `nc -vv  -n 209.85.202.27 25`